# Rails migrations: Undo default setting for a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have the problem, that I have an migration in Rails that sets up a default setting for a column, like this example:

```
def self.up
  add_column :column_name, :bought_at, :datetime, :default => Time.now
end
```

Suppose, I like to drop that default settings in a later migration, how do I do that with using rails migrations?

My current workaround is the execution of a custom sql command in the rails migration, like this:

```
def self.up
  execute 'alter table column_name alter bought_at drop default'
end
```

But I don't like this approach, because I am now dependent on how the underlying database is interpreting this command. In case of a change of the database this query perhaps might not work anymore and the migration would be broken. So, is there a way to express the undo of a default setting for a column in rails?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

#### Rails 5+

```ruby
def change
  change_column_default( :table_name, :column_name, from: nil, to: false )
end
```

#### Rails 3 and Rails 4

```ruby
def up
  change_column_default( :table_name, :column_name, nil )
end

def down
  change_column_default( :table_name, :column_name, false )
end
```

Comment: In postgres, this won't actually drop the default for `CHARACTER VARYING` columns, just set it to `NULL::character varying`.

Comment: In more recent versions, you can make it reversible. For example:  `change_column_default(:table_name, :column_name, from: nil, to: false)`

Comment: @AttilaO. I've had success running `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN type DROP DEFAULT`, no need to set it to `NULL` I think.

Comment: FYI, it looks like the reversible version that @Mark mentions was added in Rails 5+, so anything below that, you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 23):

[Sounds](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M001960&name=change_column_default) like you're doing the right thing with your 'execute', as the docs point out:

> ```
> change_column_default(table_name, column_name, default)
> ```
>
> Sets a new default value for a column.
>   **If you want to set the default value
>   to NULL, you are out of luck. You need
>   to DatabaseStatements#execute the
>   appropriate SQL statement yourself.**
>   Examples
>
> ```
> change_column_default(:suppliers, :qualification, 'new')
> change_column_default(:accounts, :authorized, 1)
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't found this hint in the docs by myself! 
Hopefull they build in the dropping of default values into migrations in future versions of rails.

Comment: This is not true anymore as of Rails 3.1.0, cfr. http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default

Answer (score 14):

The following snippet I use to make `NULL` columns `NOT NULL`, but skip `DEFAULT` at schema level:

```
def self.up
  change_column :table, :column, :string, :null => false, :default => ""
  change_column_default(:table, :column, nil)
end
```

Comment: I don't see added value in this answer since the accepted one states the same.

Answer (score -3):

Rails 4

```
change_column :courses, :name, :string, limit: 100, null: false
```

Comment: This one adds NOT NULL constraint, it has nothing to do with DEFAULT

Comment: has nothing to do with DEFAULT +1