# attr_accessor default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attr-accessor

I'm using rails and I want to make it so that `attr_accessor :politics` is set, by default, to false.

Does anyone know how to do this and is able to explain it in simple terms for me?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

### Rails 4+

```rb
class Like
  def after_initialize
    self.politics = false
  end
end

i = Like.new
i.politics #=> false
```

### Rails 3.1 and below

```rb
class Like
  attr_accessor_with_default :politics, false
end

i = Like.new
i.politics #=> false
```

### Pure Ruby

```rb
class Like
  attr_writer :politics
      
  def politics
    @politics || false
  end
end

i = Like.new
i.politics #=> false
```

Comment: Note that the example only works for a default of false. I needed a default of true, so I used: `@politics.nil? ? true : @politics`

Comment: If you're defaulting to an array, use: `def politics; @politics ||= []; end` or << won't work until you assign a value to politics some other way.

Comment: I think the `after_initialize` method suggested by Dave Newton is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

If you define your `attr_accessor`, by default the value is `nil`.  You can write to it, thereby making it `!nil`

Answer (score -1):

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
      return unless self.new_record?
      self.play_count ||= 0
    end
end
```

In my opinion, I think this answer is good. Although we are overriding the `initialize()` method but since super is called on the first line of this method, it doesn't change anything to the base class `initialize()` method, rather this is a key feature of Object Oriented programming that we can override it, and add some more functionality at the time of initialization of objects. And also the initializer will not be skipped while reading objects from the database, since `super` is called on the first line of the function.

Comment: IMO `after_initialize` is a better option than overriding a framework-overridden method, and the [Rails AR guide encourages its use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find). The issue is that AR might change from under you and change behavior.

Comment: Thanks Dave por your suggestion, I think is the best one!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the virtus gem:

https://github.com/solnic/virtus

From the README:

> Virtus allows you to define attributes on classes, modules or class instances with optional information about types, reader/writer method visibility and coercion behavior. It supports a lot of coercions and advanced mapping of embedded objects and collections.

It specifically supports [default values](https://github.com/solnic/virtus#default-values).

Answer (score -5):

I've been using this form in ActiveRecord:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

    def initialize(*args)
      super(*args)
      return unless self.new_record?
      self.play_count ||= 0
    end
end
```

Comment: You should not overwride initialize in ActiveRecord objects, use before_create instead.

Comment: why not?  The initializer is skipped only when reading objects from the database.  For a default value, you wouldn't want it overwriting info from the db anyway.

Comment: @user1144360 Because as the [Rails AR guide notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#after_initialize-and-after_find) there's an `after_initialize` provided specifically to avoid the need to override `initialize`. IMO it's safer to do so over the long term. The issue is that AR might change from under you and change behavior.

Answer (score -6):

This is not done in attr_accessor, rather, in your migration.

So .. you could perform a migration

(1) `rails g migration ChangePoliticsColumnToDefaultValueFalse`

(2) add this in `def self.up`

`def self.up change_column :your_table, :politics, :boolean, :default => 0  end`

The bottom line is that default attributes are set in migrations.

Hope this helps!

Edit:

There are some similar questions too that have been answered well:

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186400/correct-way-to-set-default-values-in-rails) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: Actually `attr_accessor` IS the correct method if you don't want your attribute stored in the database.

Answer (score -7):

attr_accessor in rails are only virtual variable which is not store in database and it can be use only until active record not save or update in application.
You can define attr_accessor in model like

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :virtual_variable
end
```

and use in form like :-

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :virtual %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :virtual %>
  </div>
```

and you can found these vartual variable value in controller param...