# RSpec - how to test default value for attribute using callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, callback

Here's my test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe League do

    it 'should default weekly to false' do
      league = Factory.create(:league, :weekly => nil)
      league.weekly.should == false
    end
  end

end
```

And here's my model:

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :weekly, :inclusion => { :in => [true, false] }

  before_create :default_values

  protected

  def default_values
    self.weekly ||= false
  end

end
```

When I run my test, I get the following error message:

```
 Failure/Error: league = Factory.create(:league, :weekly => nil)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Weekly is not included in the list
```

I've tried a couple different approaches to trying to create a league record and trigger the callback, but I haven't had any luck.  Is there something that I am missing about testing callbacks using RSpec?

Comment: Validation is run on the model before the before_create is triggered so that's why I am getting the error.  I decided to go this route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715468/attr-accessor-default-values/8775320#8775320. Now all works.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are saying is, before create, set weekly to false, then create actually sets weekly to nil, overwriting the false.

Just do

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe League do

    it 'should default weekly to false' do
      league = Factory.create(:league)  # <= this line changed
      league.weekly.should == false
    end
  end

end
```

in your test.  No need to explicitly set nil.

Comment: With the new RSpec3 you should expect(league.weekly).to be false