# Default values for model attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemodel

What's the proper way to set default values for models in Rails?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :points
end
```

I want points to start out at 0 instead of `nil`. Ideally the default value is created right away rather than waiting for the `User` to be saved into the database. But I guess using a `before_save` or database constraints work as well:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :points
  before_save :set_defaults

  private
  def set_defaults
    self.points = 0
  end
end
```

Using the latest stable Rails.

Comment: Here is a better http://stackoverflow.com/a/1188834/1765534
Posible duplication

Answer (score 8):

set it in your migration:

```
 t.integer :points, default: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value by `migration` or by using model `setter` methods.

```
change_column :user, :points, :integer, :default => 0
```

Or,

```
def points
    @points ||= 0
end
```