# Automatically save in associated datatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct Way to Set Default Values in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186400/correct-way-to-set-default-values-in-rails)

I have two data tables:

1) User

2) Profile (which has the field user_id)

They are associated through:

- User has_one Profile
- Profile belongs_to User

Is there a possibility to save some default values in the profile table each time I create a new user?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create default profile by using ActiveRecord [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Just create a method, and use it as :after_create

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile

  after_create :create_default_profile

  def create_default_profile
    profile = build_profile
    # set parameters
    profile.save
  end

end
```

build_profile builds and links an instace of Profile, but doesn't save it. create_profile is the same, but it also saves the object. For the full description, see the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

You can add attributes to both build_ and create_profile as a hash, so you probably can reduce create_default_profile to one line:

```
def create_default_profile
  profile = create_profile :some => 'attirbute', :to => 'set'
end
```

Comment: I think this could work - but how could I link the new created profile to the user I have just created...I dont' get it. What do I have to fill in the create_default_profile method?

Comment: something in the create_default_profile like profile = Profile.new(user_id:self.id)

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Thanks a lot! You are awesome! I tried it with "user_id:self_id".

Comment: One last question: Why do I have to use self.id? Why does user.id does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add default value for profile.

I am setting some values for `member_standing` and `points` attributes of profile for a user.

In create action for users controller

```rb
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  profile = @user.profiles.build(:member_standing => "satisfactory", :points => 0)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: mmmh, when I am doing this I get the error message "undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass" for UsersController#create...