# How to calculate users response rate and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to brainstorm on how I can calculate a users response rate (% of responses to messages received) and time (how fast does user responds to messages). This information would show on a users profile. I can't think of a formula that would work for this and haven't seen any other posting regarding it.

For example User A response rate is 85% and their response time is 3 days. What would be the proper way to attack this?

Messages model:

```
    attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recipient_deleted
    validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"
    has_many :notifications, as: :event
  scope :unread, -> {where('read_at IS NULL')}

    belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :recipient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'


    # Based on if a message has been read by it's recipient returns true or false.
    def read?
        self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end


    def self.received_by(user)
       where(:recipient_id => user.id)
     end


     def self.not_recipient_deleted
       where("recipient_deleted = ?", false)
     end

     def self.sent_by(user)
        Message.where(:sender_id => user.id)
      end
```

Controller:

```
  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    @messages = Message.scoped
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archived"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
    if params[:mailbox] == "unread"
    @messages = @user.unread_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  if params[:mailbox] == "trash"
    @messages = @user.deleted_messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC"
  end
  end

  def new
      @message = Message.new
      @message.conversation_id = params[:conversation_id]
    end

    def create
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])
      @message.sender_id = @user.id
      if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
        redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
      else
        render :action => :new
      end
    end

    def show
      @reply_message = Message.new
        @message = Message.find(params[:id])
        if @message.recipient == current_user
           UserMessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, current_user.id)
         end
        @message.readingmessage if @message.recipient == current_user
      end

    def reply
        @reply_message = Message.new
        @message = Message.new
        @message.conversation_id = params[:conversation_id]
    end

   def destroy
     @message = Message.find(params[:id])
     @message.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted message."
     redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
   end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user.id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end


  def update
      @message = Message.new
      if params[:reply_to]
        @reply_to = User.find_by_id(params[:reply_to])
        unless @reply_to.nil?
          @message.recipient_id = @reply_to.id
        end
      end
    end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
  end
end
```

Log:

```
2014-02-05T17:08:16Z 33906 TID-zt6cxk WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"UserMessageWorker", "args"=>[159, 2], "jid"=>"f502221628588feaa5efa7d3", "enqueued_at"=>1391619720.3566332, "error_message"=>"undefined method `messages' for #<User:0x00000101edb0a0>", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>"2014-02-05T17:02:00Z", "retry_count"=>4, "retried_at"=>2014-02-05 17:08:16 UTC}
2014-02-05T17:08:16Z 33906 TID-zt6cxk WARN: undefined method `messages' for #<User:0x00000101edb0a0>
2014-02-05T17:08:16Z 33906 TID-zt6cxk WARN: /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activemodel-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:436:in `method_missing'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:131:in `method_missing'
/Users/dating/app/workers/user_message_worker.rb:8:in `perform'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in process'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `call'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `block in invoke'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:62:in `call'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22:in `with_context'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `call'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `invoke'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:105:in `stats'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:47:in `block in process'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:86:in `do_defer'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-2.17.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:37:in `process'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

Comment: so you're sending users, from an email, back to your website, and you want to calculate the elapsed interval, response rate emails to people that view that page?

Comment: For the registered users I was unable to create a formula/code that would calculate their response rate to received messages (unread). It should show response rate is % and response time is x days. For example on https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/1349952 it shows response rate and time under their contact information.

Comment: how do you determine that one message is a response to another?

Comment: It would be based on the recipient responding to unread message from sender. This would only calculate for the original messages, not the replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you will want to store these values in the User table? I'll call those columns `average_response_time` and `response_rate`. You will also want to add a column to the User table that is a sum of all the Time between when a message is sent and when it is seen. I'll call it `response_total`.

Then put it all in a background job... or not, but I would. I like Sidekiq, and there's a great railscast about it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq).

In messages controller

```
def show
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  if @message.recipient == current_user
    UserMessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Then in app/workers/user_message_worker.rb

```
class UserMessageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(message_id, user_id)
    message = Message.find(message_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    message.read_at = Time.now
    old_msg_count = user.messages.count

    if message.save
      msg_response_time = message.read_at - message.created_at

      response_rate = (user.messages.where("read_at IS NOT NULL").count)/(old_msg_count + 1)
      response_time = ((user.average_response_time * old_msg_count)+msg_response_time)/(old_msg_count + 1)
      user.update_attributes(:response_rate => response_rate, :average_response_time => average_response_time )
    end
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure my math for the `response_time` is correct, but you should double check it. Also, depending on how accurate you want it, you may want to store `response_total` in minutes or seconds (or hours or days) so the number doesn't get huge.

Comment: If you don't want to use sidekiq, you could move all the code in the `perform` method into the controller `show` action where `perform_async` is called. If you do just remember to change the `message` and `user` variables.

Comment: [how to set defaults in migration file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186400/correct-way-to-set-default-values-in-rails)