# Rails 4: Remove not null constraint from table column with migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

Given the following `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "people", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",  null: false
    t.integer  "age"
    t.integer  "height"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "married",  default: false
    t.text     "bio"
    t.integer  "fav_number"
    t.decimal  "lucky_num",  precision: 2, scale: 2
    t.datetime "birthday"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I'd like to remove the `name` default value of `null: false`. I've tried running a separate migration with `change_column_default`, but that had no impact on `schema.rb`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it already in production? Otherwise you can simply rollback and manually remove the default.

Comment: @rails4guides.com that's what I ended up doing. I thought there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct Way to Set Default Values in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186400/correct-way-to-set-default-values-in-rails)

Answer (score 68):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQL/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-change_column_default):

```
  def up
    change_column_default :table_name, :status, 0
  end

  def down
    change_column_default :table_name, :status, nil
  end
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `:table_name` instead of `:column_name` for that first value.  `change_column_default(table_name, column_name, default) public`

Comment: I believe OP wants to remove the not null constraint... rather than changing a default value. They only mentioned `change_column_default` as something they tried, not knowing that that isn't the method they need to use.

Answer (score 32):

The 'up' function will definitely do the job when you do db:migrate.
But in the future, in some cases, like rollback, you might want a function to reverse this particular migration.

```
def up
  change_column_null :people, :name, true
end

def down
  change_column_null :people, :name, false
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Can you add an explanation as well, what is the difference to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098047/change-default-value-for-table-column-with-rails-migrations-rails-4/27266641#27266641)?

Comment: [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098047/change-default-value-for-table-column-with-rails-migrations-rails-4/27266641#27266641) refers changing the default value of a column.
my answer sets whether this column allow null value or not.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke because this answer is the only correct answer, even 7 years later.  It solves the problem, removing NOT NULL constraint, which has nothing to do with column defaults

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk I added my comment when there was no text at all. If I remove it now, ran632s comment would make less sense. And the answer still lacks the information, which you just have given. See the answers from ddebruler and Rick Smith for an example: Always explain, why this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 18):

It sounds like you're not trying to change the default value of the column, but rather to remove the NOT NULL constraint and allow null values (i.e. change from "null: false" to the default "null: true").  If that's the case, then you can use [change_column_null](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null):

```
class ChangeNameNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :people, :name, true
  end
end
```

Edit 1:- Fixed typo

Answer (score 3):

```
def change
  change_column_null(:users, :admin, false, <put a default value here> )
  # change_column(:users, :admin, :string, :default => "")
end
```

Changing a column with NULL values in it to not allow NULL will cause problems.  This is exactly the type of code that will work fine in your development setup and then crash when you try to deploy it to your *LIVE* production.  You should first change NULL values to something valid and *then* disallow NULLs.  The 4th value in `change_column_null` does exactly that. See [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null) for more details.

Also, I generally prefer to set a default value for the field so I won't need to specify the field's value every time I create a new object. I included the commented out code to do that as well.