# Default Values in Rails - Active Record after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know why in Rails 4.x, the ||= operator doesn't seem to work properly with defaulting Strings.

fails:

```
self.scheme ||= "https"
```

with an error of:

```
NoMethodError:
undefined method `scheme' for
```

works:

```
after_initialize :apply_defaults

def apply_defaults
    #remote Docker daemons use HTTPS by default
    self.scheme
    #default port for docker daemons
    self.port ||= 2376
end

#for some reason, can't use ||= and need a real method
def scheme
    self[:scheme] || 'https'
end
```

why is it that to have a default string I need a method, but the port (integer) does not?

source: [How to set default values in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186400/correct-way-to-set-default-values-in-rails)

Comment: The problem seems to be a missing `scheme` method, not the string argument or a buggy operator.

Comment: Don't set defaults after initialize

Comment: Do you have a database field "scheme" in that table?

Comment: Yes I've got scheme set on the model.  What's the proper way to have defaults?  add them to the migration?