# How to set default value from database rails if params is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hai i want to know how to set a default value from the database if my `params` is `nil`

I am trying to update a record in my database I have used this code

```
  if @sheet = Sheet.where(id: sheet_id).first_or_initialize
    @sheet.user_id = user_id
    @sheet.name = sheet_name ## I want to set a default value for this
    @sheet.save
  end
```

I want to set the default value of sheet name from database if my `params[sheet_name]` is `nil`.

**Update**
This is the thing i am trying to achieve

```
if sheet_name != nil
  @sheet.name = sheet_name
end
```

is there any short hand way of writing this

Comment: What value would be that? A "dynamic" one, or always the same value?

Comment: @SebastianPalma i need to set the value which is currently in database if params[sheet_name] is null

Comment: @spickermann i am using a method for both updation and creation. For example if i give a value into params[sheet_name] = Sheet 1 it should set the name to Sheet 1. If i try to update that record if no params[sheet_name] is given it should set the default value which is Sheet 1.

Answer (score 2):

In your example this should work:

```
if @sheet = Sheet.where(id: sheet_id).first_or_initialize
  @sheet.user_id = user_id
  @sheet.name = sheet_name.presence || 'Sheet 1'
  @sheet.save
end
```

Depending on your use-case you might want to consider [setting the default in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1186400/2483313).

Comment: I am using a method for both updation and creation. For example if i give a value into params[sheet_name] = Sheet 1 it should set the name to Sheet 1. If i try to update that record if no params[sheet_name] is given it should set the default value which is Sheet 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering but please check the comment.

Comment: @AmalTS I still think my answer should solve your question. If it does not please elaborate on what is going wrong or is missing.

Comment: What does the sheet_name.presence does ?

Comment: It calls the [`presence` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) on `sheet_name` and makes sure that empty strings get handled as `nil` and therefore still fall back to the default.

Comment: it doesn't seems to be working if param[sheet_name] is null it writes sheet_name = null

Comment: Is the attribute really named just `name`? Or should it be `@sheet.sheet_name = ...`? And how and where do you actually set `sheet_name`?

Comment: Yes, there is a shortcut for that: Exactly to code I wrote above in my answer. Therefore I am sure there must be another issue in your code outside of the example that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a default value for that column in the database by

1. create a migration using `rails g migration AddDefaultValueForSheetName`
2. add that line `change_column_default :sheets, :name, value you want to be default`
3. run the migration using `rake db:migrate`
4. in the controller use something like

```
  if @sheet = Sheet.where(id: sheet_id).first_or_initialize
        @sheet.user_id = user_id
        @sheet.name = params[sheet_name] if params[sheet_name].present?
        @sheet.save
  end
```