# how to change a text column that default to null to default to '' in a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I am trying to write a migration to handle the null -> '' conversion but it doesn't seem to be working. I have:

```
def up
  change_column :items, :detail, :text, :default => ''
end
```

Is this correct syntax?

thx

Answer (score 3):

That looks about right.

You should be aware, however, if you're using MySQL you [can not set a default value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) to a TEXT or BLOB field.

Comment: thx, didn't know that - is it normally achieved by just setting a default_values on the object in question

Answer (score 0):

Use should use `change_column_default(table_name, column_name, dafault_value)`
This question has been already asked here:
[Rails migrations: Undo default setting for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887246/rails-migrations-undo-default-setting-for-a-column)